# operator does not exist: geography <-> geography

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I've postgresql column with type

```
geography(Point,4326)
```

And I've inserted some rows to it using

```
POINT(LONG LAT)
```

That data have been inserted successfully and I can retrieve it with no problems, now I want to get the nearest entries to a specific point using the following query

```
SELECT "cafes".* FROM "cafes" ORDER BY "latlng" <-> (SELECT latlng FROM cafes WHERE id = '3') LIMIT 1
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: geography <-> geography
LINE 1: ...es".* FROM "cafes" ORDER BY "latlng" <-> (SELEC...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<->` "distance between" operator applies to PostgreSQL geometric data types, not to the PostGIS `geography` data type. With the `geography` data type you can use the PostGIS function `ST_Distance()` and find the minimum value.

```
WITH this_cafe (latlng) AS (
  SELECT latlng FROM cafes WHERE id = '3'
)
SELECT cafes.*, ST_Distance(cafes.latlng, this_cafe.latlng, 'false') AS dist
FROM cafes, this_cafe
ORDER BY dist ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Note that the third argument `useSpheroid` to the function is set to `false` which will make the function much faster. It is unlikely going to affect the result because cafes tend to lie close to each other.

This assumes that there is only 1 cafe with `id = 3`. If there could be more, then restrict the CTE to return just 1 row.

Comment: Thank you that worked... But I've another question, how can I limit the distance to 100km for example? I mean, I want to add where clause similar to this one (WHERE ST_Distance < 100m) ?

Comment: OK Man, I added the WHERE clause as follows:
WHERE ST_Distance(cafes.latlng, ST_GeomFromText(this_cafe.latlng)::geography, 'false') > 100